# has no method 'mountComponentIntoNode' with Jest + React

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

Im brand new to React as well as Jest and I thought I had a fairly simple component but I keep getting this error and I dont see any info on it in their issues on GitHub and only one React specific, not Jest, question here. Full error is: `TypeError: Object <UserInfo /> has no method 'mountComponentIntoNode'`

React Code

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-nested-router');

var user = require('../lib/stores/user');

/**
 * UserInfo
 *
 * Form for user's personal information.
**/
var UserInfo = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    user.firstName = this.refs.firstName.getDOMNode().value;
    user.lastName = this.refs.lastName.getDOMNode().value;
    user.dateOfBirth = this.refs.dob.getDOMNode().value;
    user.ssn = this.refs.ssn.getDOMNode().value;

    Router.transitionTo('/contact-info');
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <section>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label class="first-name-label" htmlFor="first-name">First Name</label>
          ... lots of inputs and labels ...
        </form>
      </section>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = UserInfo;
```

Jest Code

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
jest.dontMock('../application/views/user-info.jsx');
var React = require('react/addons');
var UserInfo = require('../application/views/user-info.jsx');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

describe('UserInfo', function () {
  it('example test only', function () {
    var userinfo = '<UserInfo />'
    TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(userinfo);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! I think I figured it out finally. I accidently had `<UserInfo />` in a string!

```
describe('UserInfo', function () {
  it('example test only', function () {
    var userinfo = <UserInfo />
    TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(userinfo);
  });
});
```

Above works!